# Kubernetes service is configured but get connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, service, ignite, gridgain

I have service configurd on my kuberntes cluster but when I try to curl ip:port I get connection refused
the following service configured :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: production
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
   - name: control-center-web
     port: 8008
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 8008
```

$ kubectl describe svc frontend

```
 Name:                    frontend
    Namespace:                production
    Labels:                   <none>
    Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                                {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"frontend","namespace":"production"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":...
    Selector:                 app=frontend
    Type:                     NodePort
    IP:                       <ip>
    Port:                     control-center-web  8008/TCP
    TargetPort:               8008/TCP
    NodePort:                 control-center-web  7851/TCP
    Endpoints:                <none>
    Session Affinity:         None
    External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
    Events:
      Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
      ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
      Normal  Type    14m   service-controller  LoadBalancer -> NodePort
```

Why do I keep getting connection refuse for ip and port that I took from the svc?

Comment: can you update this with your yaml files? Also can your show us `kubectl get svc`

Answer (score 2):

The `Endpoints` in service has got `None` instead of IPs of the pods. This happens when the selector in service `app: frontend` does not match with the selector in pod spec,